# How to user reply the post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Page:1 code behind questionview.aspx.cs

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=SARFARAZ\\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=true; database=tdf;");
        SqlDataAdapter sqlcmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from question, users where  users.user_id=question.user_id AND question_id='" + Request.QueryString["qid"] + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqlcmd1.Fill(dt);
        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
```

Page 2: Questionview.aspx

Through repeater i have display my post and reply answer but its can't showing..!
asp.net code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="container">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
           <div  class="panel-heading">

               <h2 class="panel-title"><a href="Answer.aspx?qid=<%#Eval("question_id") %>"><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Reply"></asp:Label></a></h2>
          </div><!--panel-heading-->
           <div class="panel-body">
               <h3><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("heading") %>'></asp:Label></h3>
                   <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("uimg")%>' Height="100" Width="100" />
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("question_detail") %>'></asp:Label>
               <br />
               <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("username") %>'></asp:Label>
               <br />
                 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("datetimes") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div><!--panel-heading-->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Please give me solution.......!
Now question update:
Simple when user login then the forums question willl be shown as you can watch in screen shoot 1[First Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bsxl.png). Now maker is a question and i want to reply the answer of maker question.

After clicking maker question then user will be go to maker question maker then you can also watched the question  in your computer screen [Second Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2PeN.png)that its how will be display. And simple want to this that user come and just reply the question and I am making the project of discussion forums.

Comment: THe question isn't clear - try to add explenations

Comment: First of all, you are using 2 `SQL select` queries, not sure why! , and you are not binding anything to repeater, like `Repeater1.DataSource = ds`.

Comment: Why are you assigning a value to `sdpt.SelectCommand` twice?

Comment: Please again seen it. I was update the question...! Thank You

Comment: Slightly unrelated but have you heard of SQL Injection? Your code is way too insecure:
question_id='" + Request.QueryString["qid"]    

Please close that gaping whole :)